# Detect other react instance url change

Tags: reactjs

The url changed from react instance1 to the history.push() of the react-router-dom.
Is it detectable in react instance2?

```
<body>
    <div id="react1"></div>
    <div id="react2"></div>

    <script src="./react1.js"></script>
    <script src="./react2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean that the url changed?  How many events happened?

Comment: When using history.push('/hello') in react instance1
I want to know that 'Hello' has been created in react instance2.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two different instances of React and `react-router-dom` in the same application?

Comment: you're right...